# equivalent code of libcurl c code to command line?

Tags: bash, libcurl

I have written a libcurl c code to post authentication details to site and is working fine and want to have equivalent code for the c code line in command line

code-

```
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1L);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some reading through the [`curl` documentation](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) reveals:

> **--location-trusted**

> (HTTP) Like `-L`, `--location`, but will allow sending the name + password to all hosts that the site may redirect to. This may or may not introduce a security breach if the site redirects you to a site to which you'll send your authentication info (which is plaintext in the case of HTTP Basic authentication).

And a quick test using `--libcurl <filename>` shows that it does set `CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH`.